# Prevent selecting and moving a shape created with Word VBA

Tags: vba, select, ms-word, shapes, move

I have the below VBA Word code that creates a band from the top edge to the bottom edge of the page. The code works alright. But an user can click on the shape and move it. Is there way to prevent it

```
Sub CreateColorBand()
    Dim pageWidth As Single
    Dim pageHeight As Single
    Dim bandWidthInches As Single
    Dim bandWidth As Single
    Dim bandColor As Long
    Dim bandShape As Shape
    Dim GroupShape As Shape

    ' Set the parameters
        pageWidth = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.pageWidth
        pageHeight = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.pageHeight
        bandWidthInches = 1.607
        bandWidth = InchesToPoints(bandWidthInches)
    
        Select Case Color
            Case "Indigo"
                    bandColor = RGB(51, 51, 153)
                Case "Ecru"
                    bandColor = RGB(194, 178, 128)
                Case "Gray"
                    bandColor = RGB(166, 166, 166)
                Case "Green"
                    bandColor = RGB(83, 127, 53)
            End Select

    ' Add a colored band shape
        Set bandShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, pageWidth - bandWidth, 0, bandWidth, pageHeight)
    
    ' Format the band shape
        With bandShape
            .Fill.Solid
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = bandColor
            .Line.Visible = msoFalse ' Hide the border line
            .ZOrder msoSendToBack ' Send the shape to the back, behind the text and tables
            .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
            .LockAnchor = True
        End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Can’t be done in VBA but can be done by editing the XML. See https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/09/xml-hacking-locking-graphics

Comment: Place the shape behind text in the first-page header, the header, and the even-page header. Put it in a Group Content Control in each.